# Google Map v2 android

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

Hi If I leave blank the SHA key when I create the api key, will it work? Am I right that this means that all application works?
I followed the codes given in https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#obtaining_an_api_key
When I run the app on my phone, I get error - fragment class not found. My phone is gingerbread.
Am I right to reference the whole library project in my project??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it will not work, when you enter something like `;com.example.android.mapexample` when requesting API key in google maps console, because your SHA key cannot be `""`.

Comment: What if I left the whole textbox blank? Not even ;com.example.android.mapexample

Comment: I think, that even your packagename cannot be `""`, google uses these things(sha key and packagename) to recognize your app so you must provide them in order to make it work.

Comment: One more question - Does it work on the emulator if things are ok??

Comment: it works if you make some manipulations for the emulator see more information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15172597/google-maps-api-v2-not-work-in-emulator/15177695#15177695\

Answer (score 2):

No it won't work. this is the way Google identify that the application was created on the same device as the key was produces. If you won't supply the key you wont see a map in your application.

With that said it look that you problem is not really related to the SHA1 key but ratter a wrong use of a `MapFragment`. I think that for this Android version you should use `SupportMapFragment`.